# Как обрабатывать OPTIONS запрос в express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Как правильно обрабатывать запрос методом `OPTIONS` в express.js?

Comment: Насчет этого не знаю, а с OPTIONS у меня проблемы не возникло.. router['options']('/test', function(req, res, next) {

Comment: @shatal, я отредактировал ваш вопрос, выкинув все, что не относится к делу. Обратите внимание, ru.so -- это сервис для вопросов/ответов, а не для жалоб на жизнь. А еще почитайте вот это: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Также как любой другой запрос, из документации:

> Express supports the following routing methods corresponding to HTTP
>   methods: get, post, put, head, delete, **options**, trace, copy, lock,
>   mkcol, move, purge, propfind, proppatch, unlock, report, mkactivity,
>   checkout, merge, m-search, notify, subscribe, unsubscribe, patch,
>   search, and connect.

Пример:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.options('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Проверяем:

```
➜  ~  curl -X OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/
Hello World!
```

Comment: Неплохо было бы еще и пример кода привести ;-)

Comment: @shatal, уясните для себя одну простую вещь: здесь вам _никто ничего не должен_.

Comment: добавил пример в ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Сначала не заработало, но потом создал файл с Вашим кодом и запустил только его и все как нужно отработало. Буду искать причину у себя в коде, хотя не знаю почему get, post, put отрабатывают, а options нет. И ещё раз спасибо, Вы меня спасли от мысли, что это не возможно. Я этот хелп пол дня назад прочел и у меня не получилось, ну я и начал дальше искать и увидел сообщение на англоязычной версии, что есть обрабатывается только три метода, а остальные убраны в all. Хотя он у меня тоже не работает...